# Provided id of the wrong type SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman

i am creating a simple crud project with spring boot associate with postman.i can list the records successfully.i added record success. when i tried to seach the records through postman it won't work.i got the error was Postman Provided id of the wrong type for **class com.example.demo1.Entity.Student. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long** Postman what i tried so far i attached below.

**Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Records")
public class Student 
{   
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="fname")
    private String fname;
    
    @Column(name="lname")
    private String lname;
    
    @Column(name="city")
    private String  city;
    
    
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name="salary")
    private String salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface Studentrepository extends CrudRepository<Student,Long> {
    

}
```

**Service**

```
//getting a specific record by using the method findById() of CrudRepository  
         public Student getStudentById(long id)   
         {  
         return repo.findById(id).get();  
         }
```

**Controller**

```
//creating a get mapping that retrieves the detail of a specific book  
     @RequestMapping("/student/{id}")  
     private Student getBooks(@PathVariable(name = "id") int studentid)   
     {  
     return services.getStudentById(studentid);  
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your entity and controller, you have defined id as integer. In your service , you take in a long parameter. Hence the mismatch and the error message. While sometimes cryptic, error messages usually tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You defined id as an int in your entity, but in your service and repository you are using long, decide which type you want to use, and use the same type in all of your classes.